# variable scope- how to access variable in handler method

Tags: javascript, scope, socket.io

In the following I want to reference 'foo' in the global scope. Is this possible somehow?

```
var io = require('socket.io');
io.on('connection', function (foo) {
        console.log('connection '+foo)
            foo.on("data",function(d){console.log('data from flash: ',d);});
            foo.emit("message","hello from server");
            foo.on('disconnect', function (foo) {
                console.log("disconnect");
            });
 });
```

Can any javascript-socketIO gurus tell me why the following wouldn't work...or perhaps is a bad idea. It seems to be the simplest solution

1 Define a global pointer

```
var _this=this;
```

2 In my socketIO handler make a reference to the foo(socket) object

```
_this.foo=foo;
```

3 then within my app.post simply reference  the foo object

```
_this.foo.emit(...
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why would the socket (which would be what is passed as foo), have any validity in global context? The socket is related to the connection, so any operations you want to do on the socket should be able to be achieved within local scope.

Comment: I need to access socket within my post(app.post) method..see my edited question and possible solution